# Session Variables not being passed from one view to another Django

Tags: django, session, view

Essentially I have two views in my views.py in django.

One stores the user object in the session using the following syntax:

```
request.session['current_user'] = user
```

The next view then attempts to pick some detail of user up by using:

```
request.session['current_user'].username
```

However this didnt work as it said there was no such key as 'current_user' so I printed the list of keys in each view. In the first view the list of keys was this:

```
[u'_auth_user_hash', u'_auth_user_id, u'_auth_user_backend','current_user']
```

then from the other view:

```
[u'_auth_user_hash', u'_auth_user_id, u'_auth_user_backend']
```

Any help would be great :D

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The session already stores the current user, and it is available directly via `request.user`.

Comment: Cheers I was unaware it did that :)